How to update my cart database on click of plus minus button in cart on ecommerce website with session_id()
I want to be able to update my cart table in the MySQL database when you click the plus or minus button in the cart of my e-commerce website. I want to be able to do this with session_id(), so no login and no cookies. Is this possible?
I tried this:
I also have a page called add_to_cart.php in which I set session_id() and update quantity every time someone clicks on "add to cart"
<body>
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
    <div class="cart-container" id="cart-container">
    <div class="cart">
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
            <div class="cart-item" id="cart-item" data-product-id=<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>>
                <h2><?php echo $row['productname']; ?></h2>
                <img id="img" style="border-radius:20px;width:150px" src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($row["productimage"]); ?>"/>
                <p>Price: $<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
                <div class="quantity-selector"><p>Quantity:</p>
        <button class="minus-btn" onclick="decrement(this)">-</button>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" class="quantity" value="1" min="1">
        <button class="plus-btn" onclick="increment(this)">+</button>
    </div>
                <p>Quantity: <?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></p>
                <span class="quantity">1</span>
                <p>Subtotal: $<?php echo $row['price'] * $row['quantity']; ?></p>
                
            </div>
 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
        </div>

    <script>
var item= document.getElementsByClassName("cart-item");

function increment(element) {
    //var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
    let quantityInput = element.closest("div.cart-item").querySelector(".quantity");
    var productId = element.closest("div.cart-item").getAttribute('data-product-id');
    var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    //var quantitySpan = element.closest("div.cart-item").querySelector('.quantity');
    quantityInput.value = currentValue + 1;
    //var newQuantity = parseInt(quantitySpan.innerText) + 1;
    //updateQuantity(element.closest("div.cart-item").dataset.itemId, quantityInput.value);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'update_cart.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Update the quantity in the UI
            //quantityInput.innerText = quantityInput.value;
            quantityInput.innerText = quantityInput.value;
        }
    };
    xhr.send('product_id=' + productId + '&quantity=' + quantityInput.value);
}

function decrement(element) {
    //var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
    let quantityInput = element.closest("div.cart-item").querySelector(".quantity");
    var productId = element.closest("div.cart-item").getAttribute('data-product-id');
    var currentValue = parseInt(quantityInput.value);
    if (currentValue > 1) {
        quantityInput.value = currentValue - 1;
    }
    
    //updateQuantity(element.closest("div.cart-item").dataset.itemId, quantityInput.value);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'update_cart.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Update the quantity in the UI
            quantityInput.innerText = quantityInput.value;
        }
    };
    xhr.send('product_id=' + productId + '&quantity=' + quantityInput.value);
}

and this is my 'update_cart.php' file:

<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
    // Generate a new session id if not already set
    $_SESSION['user_session'] = session_id();
}

$session_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$new_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

// Database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "luciavioleta";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Update quantity in the database
$sql = "UPDATE cart SET quantity = ? WHERE user_session = ? AND product_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("isi", $new_quantity, $session_id, $product_id);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Quantity updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating quantity: " . $conn->error;
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>


Active shopping carts, especially when they're not associated with a registered user, are seldom kept in a database. They are either kept in session variables, or client-side. If you do want to store information from the shopping card server-side, you would probably use a technique called AJAX.

Okay, how would I keep them in session variables? I thought this above was using AJAX.

Yes, I can see you're using AJAX, when looking at your code. The point I was trying to make is that keeping track of the shopping cart in the database is overkill. Shopping carts don't need that kind of persistence. Only a finished order needs to stored in a database. You also say you don't want to use cookies, but a session needs a cookie, doesn't it? You can only really work without cookies if you keep everything client-side. Pushing the session id through the URL is a bit ugly, cumbersome and unnecessary.

Okay how can I rewrite the code with session variables or client side? Thanks

You need to know two things for a basic shopping cart: The product ids and their quantity. A simple array in Javascript can hold this information. It's all you need. use the product ids as the array keys and the quantity as the array values.  You can use AJAX to retrieve products details like, name, price, code, description, image, from the server when you want to render the shopping cart. Send the array on the AJAX request and return all those details.

To make the cart persist when navigating the site you can use local storage, but storing it in the session on the server is more common. That would, normally, require a cookie.

However, we should stick to your question: "I want to be able to do this with session_id(), so no login and no cookies. Is this possible?". The answer should be: Well, it's possible to work without cookies, with some URL trickery, which PHP can do for you, but why would you want to do this? Almost all shopping carts rely on a cookie, and that makes sense.

Okay so how can I do it using cookies? Sorry I'm new to this.

Sessions in PHP are quite simple. Simply put session_start(); at the top of each PHP script in which you want to use sessions. After that you can use the $_SESSION array to store and retrieve values for a person using your website. PHP does the rest. See: Basic usage. From what I can see in your code, most of it is there. Only store the shopping cart in a database after the order is complete and the user has "registered". There's no point to store something permanently that might be abandoned in the end.
